# Set image size in powerpoint using open xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, powerpoint

Im am generating a ppt-file using this tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brian_jones/creating-a-presentation-report-based-on-data)

Step 4 describes how to swap out the image placeholder.
My images has different dimensions, which makes some images look a little bit too funny.

Is there any way to resize the placeholder so it can keep the dimensions?

Edit: Ok, a better explanation: users can upload images of them selves. The images are stored on the server. I am generating a ppt-file with one user per slide. And for every slide there will be an image, if any. I can of course get the dimensions of every image, but how do I replace the placeholder with an image of another dimension than the placeholder?

Answer (score 8):

Well, I can't tell you based on that tutorial, but I can tell you where it is done in Open XML (i.e. not the SDK).

Your picture will have an `xfrm` element with a set of values, like this:

```
    <p:spPr>
      <a:xfrm>
        <a:off x="7048050" y="6248401"/>
        <a:ext cx="972000" cy="288000"/>
      </a:xfrm>
    </p:spPr>
```

The values you want to change are the `cx` and `cy` of `a:ext`. Take your new picture's dimensions (h and w) from like a `System.Drawing.Image` object and take each of the values and multiply by 12700. So if the width of the picture is 400 pixels, the `cx` value of `a:ext` will be (400 x 12700 = 5080000).

Comment: I have been googling for a while. I cant find any examples on how to set these values. That is, to temper with the xml file.
Can you please post some url:s ?
Thanks again

Comment: @Mr. Powerpoint: Found a good article on using the Open XML SDK for creating a slide deck with images: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee412267(office.12).aspx. What is mentioned above - `<a:xfrm/>` is the `Extents` class.

Comment: Hi. Sorry forgot to thank you.
I never solved this one, I ended up cropping the image instead.
It is good enough.

/ Mr. powerpoint

Comment: I think your value of 12700 only holds true for a DPI if 72.

Comment: @Bas, that is the value that PowerPoint displays at - always. There is no other DPI for PowerPoint (no, it's never 96).

Comment: @ToddMain If I multiply by 12700 I'm getting different dimension instead of 400x400. How did you arrive at 12700. Or from where in XML I can pick the number to multiply. Thanks

Comment: @Naren Baby R, I'm not sure what number you're multiplying, but if you check above and you see the XML, you can see that the cy or cy value is the one that you would want to divide by 12700.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
```

lets assume you have your `SlidePart`

In my case I wanted to check for the alt title of the pictures and replace them if it matches to my key.

```
//find all image alt title (description) in the slide
List<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture> slidePictures = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture>()
.Where(a => a.NonVisualPictureProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Description.HasValue).Distinct().ToList();
```

now we check all the images:

```
//check all images in the slide and replace them if it matches our parameter
foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Picture imagePlaceHolder in slidePictures)
```

now in the loop we look for `Transform2D` and modify it with our value:

```
Transform2D transform = imagePlaceHolder.Descendants<Transform2D>().First();
Tuple<Int64Value, Int64Value> aspectRatio = CorrectAspectRatio(param.Image.FullName, transform.Extents.Cx, transform.Extents.Cy);
                        transform.Extents.Cx = aspectRatio.Item1;
                        transform.Extents.Cy = aspectRatio.Item2;
```

And this function looks like this:

```
public static Tuple<Int64Value, Int64Value> CorrectAspectRatio(string fileName, Int64Value cx, Int64Value cy)
{
   BitmapImage img = new();
   using (FileStream fs = new(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
   {
       img.BeginInit();
       img.StreamSource = fs;
       img.EndInit();
    }
   int widthPx = img.PixelWidth;
   int heightPx = img.PixelHeight;

   const int EMUsPerInch = 914400;

   Int64Value x = (Int64Value)(widthPx * EMUsPerInch / img.DpiX);
   Int64Value y = (Int64Value)(heightPx * EMUsPerInch / img.DpiY);

   if (x > cx)
   {
       decimal ratio = cx * 1.0m / x;
       x = cx;
       y = (Int64Value)(cy * ratio);
    }

    if (y > cy)
    {
        decimal ratio = cy * 1.0m / y;
        y = cy;
        x = (Int64Value)(cx * ratio);
    }

    return new Tuple<Int64Value, Int64Value>(x, y);
}
```

Important thing to note is that `EMU per inch` is `914400`. In most cases you just need to divide it by `96`, but for some monitors it is different. Therefore it is best to divide it the `DPI` for `x` and `y`.